# Most efficient way to find a continuous sequence of 3 elements in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, loops, comparison

I have a 2D array:

```
      winning moves = [
        ["a1","a2", "a3"],
        ["b1","b2", "b3"],
        ["c1","c2", "c3"],
        ["a1","b1", "c1"],
        ["a2","b2", "c2"],
        ["a3","b3", "c3"],
        ["a1","b2", "c3"],
        ["a3","b2", "c1"],
        ]
```

Then I have 2 other arrays of variable arbitrary lengths

```
 Player X = ["c3", "b3", "a2", "a1", "c2" ]

 Player Y = ["b1", "c1", "a3", "b2"]
```

In the above scenario, Y is a sequence that exists in wm.

I have the following way that works but is this the best way?

```
wm.each_with_index do |arr, index|

    puts "wm[#{index}]=#{arr}"
    winner = nil
    matchx = 0
    matchy = 0

    arr.each do|el|
        if(X.include?(el))
            matchx = matchx + 1
        end 
        if(Y.include?(el))
            matchy = matchy + 1
        end 
    end

    puts "matchx = #{matchx}"
    puts "matchy = #{matchy}"

    if(matchx == 3) 
        puts "winner = X"
    end

    if(matchy == 3) 
        puts "winner = Y"
    end

end
```

---

OUTPUT of the above code is this:

```
 wm[0]=["a1", "a2", "a3"]
 matchx = 2
 matchy = 1
 wm[1]=["b1", "b2", "b3"]
 matchx = 1
 matchy = 2
 wm[2]=["c1", "c2", "c3"]
 matchx = 2
 matchy = 1
 wm[3]=["a1", "b1", "c1"]
 matchx = 1
 matchy = 2
 wm[4]=["a2", "b2", "c2"]
 matchx = 2
 matchy = 1
 wm[5]=["a3", "b3", "c3"]
 matchx = 2
 matchy = 1
 wm[6]=["a1", "b2", "c3"]
 matchx = 2
 matchy = 1
 wm[7]=["a3", "b2", "c1"]
 matchx = 0
 matchy = 3
 winner =Y
```

Comment: *Y is a sequence that exists in wm.* - What is the functional logic of this.. I am not getting the connection of it.

Comment: This is how I determine the winners in a TicTacToe game. X and Y are players. The arrays are the positions they have chosen. wm is a 2D array of all the possible winning moves one can have on a TicTacToe board. After each move, I need to check if any player has won or not. Winning means a match of any 3 positions from the players array and any array in the 2D array.

Comment: if TicTacToe, better approach will be to save per column/row/diagonal per player, than after each move check is any of the above is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are playing TicTacToe you can do the next which is more effective

For each row/column/diagonal(only 2) save 2 values: the number of mark each played did on that row/column/diagonal

Each move you update the values, if one of the value reach 3 , the player won the game.
if player i play on (x,y) cell, the pseudo code code look like this

```
row[x][i]++
column[y][i]++
if (x == y) then diagonalA[i]++
if ((x + y) == 2) then diagonalB[i]++


if (row[x][i] == 3 || column[y][i] == 3 || 
      diagonalA[i] == 3 || diagonalB[i] == 3) 
           then 'player i has won'
```

**EDIT**

update the code to handle both diagonal

Answer (score 0):

I originally approached this using sets, but after seeing @vidaica's answer, it was obvious that using array intersections would be more straightforward.  The latter is equivalent to using sets (with `Set#subset?`, for example), but avoids the need to convert between arrays and sets.

```
   WM = [
      ["a1","a2", "a3"], ["b1","b2", "b3"], ["c1","c2", "c3"],
      ["a1","b1", "c1"], ["a2","b2", "c2"], ["a3","b3", "c3"],
      ["a1","b2", "c3"], ["a3","b2", "c1"],
      ]

    def find_winner(x_moves, y_moves)
      return "No winner" if x_moves.size < 3 
      3.upto(x_moves.size) do |i|
        if (w = win?(x_moves.first(i)))
          return "X wins with #{w}"
        elsif i <= y_moves.size && (w = win?(y_moves.first(i)))
          return "Y wins with #{w}"
        end
      end
      return "No winner"
    end     

    def win?(moves)     
      WM.find { |m| (m & moves).size == 3 }
    end

    puts find_winner([], [])
       # => No winner
    puts find_winner(["b1"], ["c3"])
       # => No winner
    puts find_winner(["b1", "c1", "a3", "b2"], ["c3", "b3", "a2", "a1"])
      # => X wins with ["a3", "b2", "c1"]
    puts find_winner(["b1", "c1", "a3", "b2"], ["c3", "b3", "a2"])
      # => X wins with ["a3", "b2", "c1"]
    puts find_winner(["b1", "a2", "a3", "c2", "c1"], ["c3", "b3", "a1", "b2"])
      # => Y wins with ["a1", "b2", "c3"]
    puts find_winner(["b1", "a2", "b2", "c3", "c1"], ["a1", "b3", "c2", "a3"])
      # => No winner
```